# Code runs but nothing is displayed it just shows the code is running until I manually stop it

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char name[20];

   printf("Enter your name: ");
   scanf("%s", name);

   printf("Hello %s ... Let's have fun !!! You=X | Computer=O\n", name);   
}
```

This code runs but does not display anything, however when I delete everything after printf("Enter your name: "); this code runs perfectly and displays "Enter your name:".I am running this code on visual studios code, can someone please help me. Thank you

I have tried everything possible but nothing worked

Comment: Why have you tagged Java and C#? Your code is in no way related to these languages. Yes, tagging unrelated languages will get more exposure for your question, but as you can see it drew my downvote. Not all attention is good. Please treat this site and its members with respect in future.

Comment: @colonel bond – Please enumerate _everything possible_ you _have tried_.

Comment: What happens if you change to `printf("Enter your nick name:\n");` in the code which does print? I ask because I want to make sure that you do in fact compile, link and run the source code you think you do. Please also state what input you use. There are lots of names out there which would get your assumption of max 20 characters in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

> This code runs but does not display anything

It doesn't display anything because of (line) buffering.

Insert `fflush(NULL);` between `printf` and `scanf`, and it will start working as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have just tried this but the code only ran up to printf and every other thing did not run.

Comment: How do you know that _every other thing did not run_?

Comment: Because, It only showed enter you name(the printf statement) and it does not allow me enter anything and when I click enter nothing happened

Comment: In which way are you prevented from entering anything? Does it terminate before? Does it fail to present you with a dialog with an editable text field? What happens if you type "me" into the dark, followed by hitting the "enter" key?

Comment: Yes It fails to present me with a dialog box with an editable text field, it just show "enter your name", however the code still keeps running until I manually terminate it but it does not allow me enter any text and when I hit enter nothing happens

Comment: The code is not supposed to open a dialog box. You need to enter the name in the same terminal window that shows "Enter your name".